# Symfony 3: links work in dev, fail in test

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I've developed a web application using Symfony framework, and it's working correctly on my dev pc:

- Debian 8.x
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7.0
- Symfony 3.3
- Mariadb 10

Now I've followed the same steps to install it on a test server: install composer, Symfony, etc. The test server has the same software as listed above, except the OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

The problem is that in test, only the home page works, and linking to any other path gets 404.  The homepage does not make a database connection, but apparently its controller is executing and the styles and templates are OK.  The links themselves are correct and relative.  There's a controller with annotated route for each page.  The `routing.yml` looks like this on both servers:

````
```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```
````

Symfony defaults to a prod environment, but putting `app_dev` in the URL or in apache's `dir.conf`  - in attempt to get some form of debugging - gets a white-out, zero content page.

I've checked that the following on the test box are identical as on the dev:

- `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (directory block is identical: `/srv/www/sitename`)
- `/etc/apache2/sites-available/sitename.conf` (minimally configured)
- `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dir.conf` (has 'app.php' in the list of defaults)
- verified that all code and template files are present and unchanged from dev
- made permissions and ownership on the project directory the same as in dev, on all code files, cache and logs
- turned on Apache mod.rewrite (this and cache clearing made the home page appear)
- cleared cache (helped to make home page appear)

Only the `parameters.yml` is different because test is looking to a new database (but a database non-connection doesn't explain it as even linking to a static page `/about` fails).

I must be missing something really basic. Still looking for any other possible differences between the environments.  Web searching gets mostly info about creating custom 404 pages, or routes not working at all.

Thanks Davi and Nando...

- We're not set up for Vagrant or VMs and can't take the time right now, but it looks like a way forward that would avoid this kind of issue.
- Symfony logs just say path not found. Apache logs show it's looking for a physical path like the URL route which implies the Symfony router is not happening. Next I'll try updating Symfony as this might fill in any missing pieces.

Update 2018-01-12: I found a workaround - it does not explain the problem described so I don't consider it a solution.

I simply copied the whole working dev directory with all contents, into the web root parent directory on the test server, and pointed the Apache VH to it. All I had to change was the database info and dev versus prod settings (affecting error display etc.). And to my surprise this "just works".

Presumably this is not considered a best practice, I now need to find a better way.

Comment: I would also fire up a vagrant box with Ubuntu 16.04 and see if the code behaves the same way on the vagrant box as the test environment. In my past experience its usually been the rewrite.mod for Apache but you have already checked that. Try troubleshooting with a vagrant box you might find something you missed on the test server.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the apache and Symfony log files? Do you have any .htaccess files and are they on the test server as well? Have you tried mod_rewrite with a simple script?